# How can I find out the COM number of a serial device?

Tags: windows-7, putty, com

today I had to configure an Ethernet Switch *(AT-8000GS/48)* via serial console to turn on stacking mode and so on. I used a RJ45 to Serial-9-Pin to USB adaptor.

First, I tried to use PuTTY under Windows 7. After selecting Serial Connection it asks for the device name like `COM1` and a speed. A colleague told me the speed, but *I had no idea how to find out the device name*. Device Manager only says "Serial USB Adaptor".

Finally I booted up Ubuntu and connected via PuTTY, because `dmesg` told the new device name.

### TL;DR

**How can I find out the name of the serial port on Windows?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to `Device Manager`
2. Click `Ports`
3. Find your `Serial USB Adapter` in the list
4. `Right click` the device, and click `Properties`

[image]

5. Go to `Port Settings`, then `Advanced`

[image]

6. Here, you should have a drop down box where you can choose the COM port.

Some instructions for this with pictures can be found [here](http://plugable.com/2011/07/04/how-to-change-the-com-port-for-a-usb-serial-adapter-on-windows-7).

Comment: There is no Ports-Tab... http://prntscr.com/a1079g
It seems, Windows doesn't even recognize the device correctly

Comment: @Hendrik Yep, you're missing some drivers there. Can you `double click` it, go to `Details` and in the drop down click `Hardware IDs`, then post the information in the first line so we can establish the driver it needs?

Comment: Oh man, now it started to install the drivers automatically. I think the reason is, that I had no internet connection in the switch room...

Comment: @Hendrik Things should be a lot easier to work out from here then :)

Comment: Thanks for your time ;) It shows as `COM3`

Answer (score 0):

The COM port can be found in the device manager:

1. Run `devmgmt.msc`
2. Open `ports` tab.
3. Here you will find the listed COM port devices, and their numbers. `COM1, COM2`

Example:

[image]